# Redisplay div after display none

Tags: css, display

I'm hoping to do something simple and googling hasn't yielded results I could understand (I'm still something of a rookie.) I'm hoping to set display to none for a div, but then later make that div come back. I'm failing to do so. See the snippet attached, I've tried "Initial" and "Reset" but to no avail. Any suggestions?

```js
function hideBtnClick(){
  innerBlock.style.display = "none";
}


function showBtnClick(){
  innerBlock.style.display = "reset";
}
```

```css
#outerBlock{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFCC33;
}

#innerBlock{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerBlock">
   <div id="innerBlock"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="hideBtnClick()">Hide</button>

<button type="button" onclick="showBtnClick()">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change **reset** to **block**

```
innerBlock.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this for a div:

```
innerBlock.style.display = "block";
```

Or this for a span:

```
innerBlock.style.display = "inline";
```

For more information on CSS display options, visit:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Using standard JavaScript (ES Script), you'll need to use:

```
document.getElementById("innerBlock").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for display div :

```
document.getElementById("innerBlock").style.display = "block";
```

**check snippet below. its work fine**

```js
function hideBtnClick(){
  document.getElementById("innerBlock").style.display = "none";
}


function showBtnClick(){
  document.getElementById("innerBlock").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#outerBlock{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FFCC33;
}

#innerBlock{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerBlock">
   <div id="innerBlock"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="hideBtnClick()">Hide</button>

<button type="button" onclick="showBtnClick()">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

After **display:none;** we can redisplay div element using standard javascript

```
document.getElementById('div_ID').style.display = "block";
```